# My index.php file Continues to Revert Itself Once Refreshing My Website?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Stack O. Members.

According to my CPA logs I've had this  issue since August 18th, but I had a few personal situations that distracted me from some maintenance. However, once I come back I noticed **all** my index.php files have been reverted.

What do I mean exactly? Well I run a Cloaker Script known as FraudBuster to cloak my websites. I have it installed on my main domain, and all my add-on domains have to use a script in order for it to execute via index.php. I've had this working since April and out of nowhere I'm getting this glitch. It should also be known I use wordpress for ALL my add-on sites. The only recent site that has been added has been my girlfriend's fashion blog, and it's the only thing I can re-direct my attention to at the time. My CPA cloak sites are pretty much set and forget, I have had these set up for months without touching them and they just seemed to edit themselves and continue to do so.

In a normal procedure to install my cloaker, the index.php will look something like this:

/home/xxxxxx/public_html/tftbiz/index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
ob_start();

//ADVANCED fraudbuster TEMPLATE
//ONLY USE WHEN YOU KNOW WHAT YOUR DOING

//define critical variables - dont change!
define('APPLOC','/home/thealey9/public_html/');
$_GET['clid'] = 'sycj8o7';

//load the fraudbuster logic
include(APPLOC.'go.php');

//decide what to do
if ( $isItSafe ) {
    //ok - alls safe - do your stuff
    fraudBuster();
}

//include your safe landing page below this comment
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
?>
```

There, I hit save, it saves, then when verifying the redirect I get this meaning it works (edited out URLs for examples):

**[{"url": "good", "status": 302}, {"url": "good redirect", "status": 200}]**

So far so good right? Now here's where the problem lies:

Once I actually visit said website, it won't redirect, instead it'll load for a bit and then just goes on the site as if the script never existed. I revisit my cPanel and once again, as furious as it is for me, reverts back to this code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

There, back to as if I never placed the script. It seems like once it logs in WP there seems to be something that modifies my index on ALL domains with WP installed to be like this. There was only one plugin installed by my GF called "Social Media Feather", and that's all I kind of know. All sites operate as normal. It's like something is giving it permission to erase this code as a sort of security measure, which is odd since as I said, have had no problems with this for months.

Please share your amazing knowledge with me. ): An inexperienced server guy will forever appreciate it.